# Can't access my router via 192.168.0.1 any more

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, home-networking

I can't access the router any more via the normal IP. I used to access it through 192.168.0.1.

The reason why I can't just reset the router is that it would change the outside IP address from my service provider. However, I need my outside IP to stay the same.

I have a Thomson TWG87OUG router.

Comment: Please tell us what exactly was changed, from the old value to the new value

Comment: no idea if this is the case for you, but at least 3 cheap routers I've had in past stopped allowing management connections in the weeks before they finally stopped passing traffic entirely. how old is your router? many home routers can only be trusted for three or four years.

Comment: I changed nothing since I restarted it to fix the same error/bug ... temporary though ... Its about two years old, but i think its an old model.

Comment: oh yea, and before the reset (but almost a year a go) I opened the port 80 to have access to a pc. But thats it. Ok, I also changed my password ;)